# regular expression in groovy to replace string starting with multiple - character

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm storing the content of a file in a String variable `String fileContents = new File('file location').text` , string contains multiple lines of data as shown below

```
 Sample text 
--- Some text---- 
Another Sample text
-- Some more text ------
--Again some more text
More Sample text
```

Need help in...
1. removing the data which starts with two or more '-' character (w\o quote) till the end of line.
2. removing texts between multiple - character.

So, the expected output should be like

> Sample text
>
> Another Sample text
>
> More Sample text

Comment: what language? c# a string is just an array you can just check to see if `str[0] == '-' && str[1] == '-'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```
^\s*--+.*$
```

And replace by empty string. Make sure to use multiline flag.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nH8aC1/1)

**Code:**

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?m)^\\s*--+.*$", "");
```

Comment: This worked!! with addition of \ character, just before the $ I had to use escape '\' character. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the multiline flag. It makes the difference between failure and success, at least in Jenkins, when attempting to match (and replace) beginning of lines using regex. Something like: `(^\\s*)` doesn't work to match white spaces on beginning of line(s). But `(?m)(^\\s*)` does.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is the new-lines. The lines are easy to filter out, but you end up with empty lines. This code:

```
def s = '''Sample text 
--- Some text---- 
Another Sample text
-- Some more text ------
--Again some more text
More Sample text'''

println s.replaceAll(/(?m)^--.*$/, '')
```

Produces:

```
Sample text 

Another Sample text


More Sample text
```

What you can do is process the String as a List, so that you can drop the offending lines, and then convert it back to a String:

```
println s.split(/\n/).findAll { !(it =~/(?m)^--.*$/) }.join('\n')
```

Produces:

```
Sample text 
Another Sample text
More Sample text
```